# Configuring Analytics with APIM 4.0.0 not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Configuring Analytics with APIM 4.0.0 not working.also https://analytics-event-auth.choreo.dev/auth/v is not reachable

```
ERROR - EventHubClient Recoverable error occurred when creating Eventhub Client. Retry attempts will be made in 5 min. Reason :Exception class feign.FeignException$NotFound occurred.
```